# How to give java.util.Properties object to spring to resolve properties values in spring like ${mail.port} from the Properties object

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am creating a stand alone jar of a spring application, it will be a utility service, so i will get object of  java.util.Properties and i need to use this properties in my spring application,

so i need to do is create a class that takes Properties object as argument in its constructure

what i have done is

```
public class MailService {
public MailService(Properties properties) {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pops = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            pops.setProperties(properties);
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = null;
            try {
                ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/resources/xml/spring/mailservice_context.xml");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ctx != null) {
                    ctx.close();
                    ctx = null;
                }
            }

    }
}
```

**and i want "mail.host" , "mail.port" from the properties object that i have passed in constructor of  MailService**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${mail.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">${mail.transport.protocol}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">${mail.smtps.auth}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">${mail.smtps.starttls.enable}</prop> 
                <prop key="mail.debug">${mail.debug}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How i can get this values from properties object of java , **i am using spring 4.1**

Comment: I recommend using Spring Boot and `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines:

```
    ctx.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(pops);
    ctx.refresh();
```

After:

```
ctx = new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/resources/xml/spring/mailservice_context.xml");
```

This will set the properties within the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and the `.refresh()` will load them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used to load database configuration file at application start up:

```
System.setProperty("db.config", options.getDbConfigFilePath());
```

where `options.getDbConfigFilePath()` is a string with filePath (passed from apache cli)

and in the context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${db.config}"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    </bean>
```

the `jdbc` parameters comes from db.config file

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i have to pass this properties from  java.util.Properties object i don't have any file